# onclick event inside tooltipster

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltipster

I'm using tooltipster with HTML content and need to hook onclick of an element within the HTML content. my code looks like this:

```
    $('.groups-tooltip').tooltipster({            
        contentCloning: true,
        trigger: 'custom',
        interactive: true,
        contentAsHTML: true,
        triggerOpen: {
            mouseenter: true
        },
        triggerClose: {
            mouseleave: true
        },

        functionReady: function(instance, helper){   
            $(".tooltip-template-div").hide();
            $('.tooltip-template-span').on("click", function(){ 
                console.log("Clicked!");
            });  

            instance.content($('#tooltip-template').html());
        }      
    });
```

*tooltip-template* is just a div container for the *tooltip-template-div* and *tooltip-template-span* elemnts.

the

```
$(".tooltip-template-div").hide();
```

part is working well but the onclick hook does not seem to have any effect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the event listener before inserting the html:

Try reversing the order

```
  functionReady: function(instance, helper){ 
       instance.content($('#tooltip-template').html());  
        $(".tooltip-template-div").hide();
        $('.tooltip-template-span').on("click", function(){ 
            console.log("Clicked!");
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should bind click event before initialize tooltipster.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tooltip-template-span').on('click', function() {
      alert("Clicked!");
    });

   $('.groups-tooltip').tooltipster({            
        contentCloning: true,
        trigger: 'custom',
        interactive: true,
        contentAsHTML: true,
        triggerOpen: {
            mouseenter: true
        },
        triggerClose: {
            mouseleave: true
        },

        functionReady: function(instance, helper){
            $(".tooltip-template-div").hide();
            $('.tooltip-template-span').click();
            instance.content($('#tooltip-template').html());
        }   
        }
   );
});
```

You can check from https://jsfiddle.net/8jmt0he6/